# Can i reference a Dockerfile in a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile that creates the build image I want to use here: `~/build/Dockerfile` then I use a standard image to deploy

The image built from `~/build/Dockerfile` is not Published anywhere, I know I can simply copy paste the one Dockerfile into the other, however it would be better if I could simply reference it so..

Is it possible to somehow reference the Dockerfile itself when deploying?

like so:

```
FROM [insert something that creates an image using ~/build/Dockerfile] as build-env
... build operations ....

FROM some-image
COPY --from=build-env /built .
ENTRYPOINT [blah]
```

This won't work but is there some other way to accomplish this?

Comment: As https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/ says FROM only has an <image> as parameter, not a <dockerfile>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally things in Docker space like the `docker run` command and the FROM directive will use a local image if it exists; it doesn't need to be pushed to a repository.  That means you can build your first image and refer to it in the later Dockerfile by name.  (There's no way to refer to the other Dockerfile *per se*.)

Newer versions of Docker have an extended form of [the Dockerfile COPY command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) which

> accepts a flag `--from=<name|index>`....  In case a build stage with a specified name can’t be found an image with the same name is attempted to be used instead.

So if you ahead of time run

```
docker build -t build-env ~/build
```

then the exact syntax you show in your proposed Dockerfile will work

```
FROM some-image
COPY --from=build-env /built .
```

and it doesn't matter that the intermediate build image isn't actually pushed anywhere.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know this!

Comment: seems `COPY` way not reuse the layer of the base image ?

Comment: It won't; it will create a new layer in the new image, though this rarely matters in practice.  Consider asking a new question if you have a specific problem around this.

Answer (score 4):

No you can't do it because you have to provide an image to `FROM`.

Change the `COPY` line to

```
COPY --from=step1 /built .
```

And write a script to build your image:

```
cd path1
docker build -t step1 .
cd path2
docker build -t final_image .
```

(if you don't want to hard code `step1` in the Dockerfile, replace it with a var and call with `ARG`)